# "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" on simple python print() method

Tags: python

I get the message "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF" on Python when typing the very simple script below. What have I done wrong and what does this message mean? Many thanks.

```
c = 5
d = c*c

print("the type of d is"+ str(type(d))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add `)` on the end!

Answer (score -2):

add ) at the end of 4th line

this type of error usually occurs when there is no matching closing parenthesis for the opening

**CORRECTED**

c = 5
d = c*c

print("the type of d is"+ str(type(d)))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please think twice about posting an answer to a question that already has an accepted answer which clearly addresses and solves the original poster's issue. In this case, the information you've provided does not add to what's already been stated.