# When executing code Unexpected EOF while Parsing?

Tags: python

I tried to use this code i found on the internet to test some stuff
my code:

```
print('what is your age')
myAge = input()
print('you will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1 ) + 'in one year'
```

but did not work and said unexpected EOF in parsing
(i am new to this stuff and im just testing these stuff this out)

Comment: Please post full error text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" on simple python print() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313742/syntaxerror-unexpected-eof-while-parsing-on-simple-python-print-method)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the last print bracket:

```
print('what is your age')
myAge = input()
print('you will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1 ) + ' in one year')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of no ')' at the end of 3rd line it throws error

```
myAge = input('what is your age\n')
print('you will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in one year')
```

We can combine the first print line and input () as

```
myAge = input('what is your age\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

use have missing `)`

use the format method , much readable not casting

```
print('what is your age')
myAge = int(input())
print('you will be {} in one year'.format(myAge+1))
```